# Merge Sort comparison measurements close to worst case

Tags: python, mergesort

Could someone explain why my measurements are not close to the average (0.74 * n * log2(n)), but are closer to the worst case (roughly 0.91 * n * log2(n))?

This is what I already tried:

- Using log instead of log2 (This resulted in more comparisons than the worst case)
- Using a random seed
- Using a different algorithm
- Running for 10 & 100 seconds instead of 1 second
- Increasing the steps to 1000.
- Only increasing the comparisons for successful comparisons (This resulted in less comparisons than the best case)

[image: Merge Sort]

```py
try:
    from matplotlib import pyplot, ticker
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("\please pip install matplotlib\n")
    exit(0)
from numpy import log2
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from multiprocessing.managers import ListProxy
from numpy import linspace, ndarray
from random import seed, shuffle
SEED: str = "Philip Dutré"
STEPS: int = 100
TIMEOUT: float = 1.0
def merge_sort(a: list[int]) -> int:
    aux: list[int] = [0] * len(a)
    return merge_sort_(a, aux, 0, len(a) - 1)
def merge_sort_(a: list[int], aux: list[int], lo: int, hi: int) -> int:
    if hi <= lo:
        return 0
    mid: int = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
    return merge_sort_(a, aux, lo, mid) + \
    merge_sort_(a, aux, mid + 1, hi) + \
    merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi)
def merge(a: list[int], aux: list[int], lo: int, mid: int, hi: int) -> int:
    comparisons: int = 0
    for k in range(lo, hi + 1): aux[k] = a[k]
    i: int = lo; j: int = mid + 1
    for k in range(lo, hi + 1):
        if i > mid:             a[k] = aux[j]; j += 1
        elif j > hi:            a[k] = aux[i]; i += 1
        elif aux[j] < aux[i]:   a[k] = aux[j]; j += 1; comparisons += 1
        else:                   a[k] = aux[i]; i += 1; comparisons += 1
    return comparisons
def merge_sort_worst(n: ndarray[float]) -> int:
    return n * log2(n)
def merge_sort_average(n: ndarray[float]) -> int:
    return 0.74 * n * log2(n)
def merge_sort_best(n: ndarray[float]) -> int:
    return n * log2(n) / 2
def run(sizes: ListProxy, comparisons: ListProxy) -> None:
    size: int = 1
    while True:
        arr: list[int] = list(range(size))
        shuffle(arr)
        comparisons.append(merge_sort(arr))
        sizes.append(size)
        size *= 2
def main():
    seed(SEED)
    with Manager() as manager:
        sizes: ListProxy = manager.list()
        comparisons: ListProxy = manager.list()
        process: Process = Process(target=run, args=(sizes, comparisons))
        process.start()
        process.join(timeout=TIMEOUT)
        process.terminate()
        n: ndarray[float] = linspace(1, sizes[-1], STEPS)
        pyplot.figure(num=f'Merge Sort')
        pyplot.title(f'Merge Sort (seed: {SEED}, {STEPS} steps, {TIMEOUT} sec)')
        pyplot.xlabel('# Elements')
        pyplot.ylabel('# Comparisons')
        formatter = ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:,.0f}")
        pyplot.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        pyplot.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        pyplot.scatter(sizes, comparisons, label="Measurements")
        pyplot.plot(n, merge_sort_average(n), label="Average Case (~0.74nlgn)", linestyle='dotted')
        pyplot.plot(n, merge_sort_best(n), label="Best Case (~nlgn/2)", linestyle='dotted')
        pyplot.plot(n, merge_sort_worst(n), label="Worst Case (~nlgn)", linestyle='dotted')
        pyplot.legend()
        pyplot.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you think you are measuring?:

Comment: The number of comparisons.

Comment: Where did the numbers 0.74 and 0.91 come from?

Comment: 0.74 comes from my text book. 0.91 is just a fit for the curve I'm getting.

Comment: I don't know what your text book is and what it says.

Comment: My teacher told us that the average number of comparisons is 0.74 * n * lg(n). But that's assuming more optimizations.

Comment: I wonder why they said that. I don't see a reason for it.

Comment: He just forgot to mention that that's assuming optimisations. OK?

Comment: We don't know those optimizations, so I don't see how we could answer this...

Comment: That's literally the answer on my question... it's close to worst case, because my implementation isn't as optimised as the version he referred to: 1. Switch to insertion sort for small arrays 2. Only merge when necessary 3. Use same aux array (additional memory) each time

Answer (score 1):

For pseudo random data, the expected number of comparisons is close to worst case, because the probability is low for reaching the end of one sub-array significantly before reaching the end of the other sub-array in a merge, with the average merge needing about n-2 comparisons for truly random data of large elements (say 256 bit integers).

I used this random number generator for 64 bit unsigned integers and for large arrays (10^8 elements), I'm getting close to worst case of .99 (n ceil(log2(n)) - 2^ceil(log2(n)) + 1).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis

```
uint64_t rnd64()   // random 64 bit unsigned integer
{
static uint64_t r = 0ull;
    r = r * 6364136223846793005ull + 1442695040888963407ull;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that: > Only increasing the comparisons for successful comparisons (This resulted in less comparisons than the best case)

Comment: @Nineteendo  - I realized my mistake, and lost a rewrite to my answer. It's fixed now.

Comment: Technically the answer would be that my implementation is sub-optimal. Resulting in a low probability of fast merges.

Comment: @Nineteendo - For random data, the number of comparisons will be near worst case. I've since done a web search and found [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/82972/39465). I updated my answer to include a wiki link about the number of comparisons for random data.